# Exemplo de Configuração no Swagger Secutiry com Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, swagger

Eu estou fazendo uma API documentada no swagger, quando eu entro na url da minha api, aparece para fazer uma autenticação, pois tem uma classe WebSecurityConfig que faz isso pra mim, porém eu queria fazer uma autenticação para os métodos da minha API, alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Docket config:

```
@Bean
public Docket userApi() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
    .select()
    .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
    .paths(Predicates.not(PathSelectors.regex("/error.*")))
    .paths(PathSelectors.any())
    .build()
    .apiInfo(metaData());

}
```

WebSecutiryConfig:

```
    package com.restfulproject.crud;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
      throws Exception {
        auth
          .inMemoryAuthentication()
          .withUser("user")
            .password("password")
            .roles("USER")
            .and()
          .withUser("admin")
            .password("admin")
            .roles("USER", "ADMIN");

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
          .authorizeRequests()
          .anyRequest()
          .authenticated()
          .and()
          .httpBasic()
          .and()
          .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Comment: *quando eu entro na url da minha api, aparece para fazer uma autenticação, ... porém eu queria fazer uma autenticação para os métodos da minha API* - Não entendi, você quer autenticação na API, e disse que já está fazendo autenticação na API, qual o problema?

Comment: Eu quero fazer a autenticação dos métodos da API

Comment: certo, você tem um método de autenticação por usuário e senha?

Comment: Isso mesmo, porém queria usar a segurança do swagger